# Parametrized types and equality in Haskell

Tags: haskell, equality, typeclass

I am implementing an union-find data structure in Haskell.

I wanted to use parametrized types but I am facing a little issue when I try to compare the objects I use as parameters.

```
data UnionFindElement valueType =
    RootElement valueType |
    ElementWithParent valueType (UnionFindElement valueType)

holds :: UnionFindElement valueType -> valueType -> Bool
holds (RootElement v) value = v == value
```

It seems that equality is not defined.

```
No instance for (Eq valueType)
  arising from a use of `=='
In the expression: v == value
```

How can I restrict valueType to consider only types with a defined equality relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`holds :: (Eq valueType) => UnionFindElement valueType -> valueType -> Bool`

`(Eq valueType) =>` means `valueType` is from class `Eq` (equatable values), and the construct exists exactly to be able to restrict types of generic parameters.

Please note this also works on data declarations and several other places. You can learn more on http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types#Type_constraints

For a more general overview, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad-hoc_polymorphism

Comment: I added two more, as you seem to like links :)

Comment: As the article states, constraints on data declarations (i.e. `data (Eq a) => A a = A a`) don't work as expected and are deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Vladislav's excellent answer, when faced with such a problem where I'm not sure of a type, I often omit the type and take advantage of Haskell's type-inferencing capabilities by loading the code into GHCi and (deferentially :) ) asking Haskell to tell me what it inferred.  That is, put this code, which is exactly the same as yours except without an explicit type for `holds`, into GHCi:

```
data UnionFindElement valueType =
    RootElement valueType |
    ElementWithParent valueType (UnionFindElement valueType)

holds (RootElement v) value = v == value
```

and check the type:

```
ghci> :t holds
holds :: Eq a => UnionFindElement a -> a -> Bool
```

which, other than alpha substitution, is exactly what Vladislav gave.